# Using Typegoose with GraphQL

Tags: mongoose, graphql, nestjs, typegoose

I am trying to use typegoose with graphql. I have a list of nested object within another object. I have defined the classes as follows

```
@ObjectType()
export class ChildClass {
  @prop()
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  someField: string;

  @prop()
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  anotherField: string;
}

@ObjectType()
@modelOptions()
export class ParentClass extends Typegoose {
  @prop()
  @Field(() => String)
  someField: string;

  @prop()
  @Field(() => [ChildClass], { nullable: 'itemsAndList' })
  children: ChildClass[];
}
```

When i call the following query

```
query {
  parentClass {
    someField
    children {
      someField
      anotherField
    }
  }
}
```

it always gives me `null` for the children's `someField` and `anotherField`. However, if i use mongoose instead of typegoose, it works correctly. MongoDb is returning fine while using typegoose. Its the conversion to graphql thats going wonky.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering around a bit, finally got it why this was happening. Updating the model to be like

```
  @prop( { type: () => [ChildClass] } )
  @Field(() => [ChildClass], { nullable: 'itemsAndList' })
  children: ChildClass[];
```

does the magic. As per the [documentation](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/decorators/prop/#array-options)